# Error in Update Statement in Access

Tags: ms-access

I have to update 3 values in a table named `tbl_InvoicewiseDetails` for which I am using `UPDATE` statement. However I am getting an error no.3144 SYNTAX Error in UPDATE Statement.

I have the following code:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tbl_InvoicewiseDetails" _    
    & "Set [Form Status] = " & "Received" & "" _
    & "Set [Form No] = " & Me.FormSerialNo & "" _
    & "Set [Form Amount] =" & Forms![ReceivedbyPBC]![tbl_tempFormDetails].Form![InvoiceValue] & "" _
    & "WHERE [Year&Invoice] =" & Forms![ReceivedbyPBC]![tbl_tempFormDetails].Form![Year&Invoice] & ";"
```

Pls help

This is the SQL query copied from SQL View of Query builder :-

```
UPDATE tbl_InvoiceWiseDetails 
SET tbl_InvoiceWiseDetails.[Form Status] = "Received", 
    tbl_InvoiceWiseDetails.[Form No] = [Forms]![ReceivedbyPBC]![FormSerialNo], 
    tbl_InvoiceWiseDetails.[Form Amount] = [Forms]![tbl_tempFormDetails]![InvoiceValue]
WHERE 
    (((tbl_InvoiceWiseDetails.[Year&Invoice])=[Forms]![tbl_tempFormDetails]![Year&Invoice]));
```

Hope this is helpful

Comment: Try printing that SQL statement.

Comment: Also, add some spaces between your keywords, this thing really needs to be formatted...

Comment: I tried after replacing the set with , but still the errors are there

Comment: Why a -1 without comment ? Nothing wrong with that question !

Comment: Instead of directly executing your SQL statement, assign it to a string variable, `Debug.Print` that variable, then [edit] your question to show us *exactly* what your actual SQL command looks like. I suspect that there are multiple issues with it.

Answer (score 0):

Should be only one `SET` I think. Replace all following `SET` by `,`.

Also `CurrentDb.Execute` will NOT work if you have references to forms. You MUST use `DoCmd.RunSql` then. (**EDIT**: I realize the form references are evaluated before, so problem is not there).

I suggest you assign the statement to a variable and `Debug.Print` the variable.
Also

```
& "Set [Form Status] = " & "Received" & "" _
```

should read

```
& "Set [Form Status] = 'Received'" & _
```

Is [Form No] a number ? If it's a string, you need to provide quotes, like this:

```
& "Set [Form No] = '" & Me.FormSerialNo & "'" _
```

Comment: FormNo. is text & Form amount is Number

Comment: I again tried to update only one field & now my code is                       CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tbl_InvoicewiseDetails" _
    & "Set [Form Status] = 'Received'" & _
    & "WHERE [Year&Invoice] ='" &  Forms![ReceivedbyPBC]![tbl_tempFormDetails].Form![Year&Invoice] & "')"

Comment: And ? still error ? Do you have any date field in there ?

Comment: You should rather show the statement as produced by the `Debug.Print` !

Comment: Sir I tried to modified my code & it worked for one field & the code is here :-                                         CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tbl_InvoicewiseDetails " _
     & "Set [Form Status] =  'Received' " & _
    "WHERE [Year&Invoice] =" & "'" & Forms![ReceivedbyPBC]![tbl_tempFormDetails].Form![Year&Invoice] & "';"

Comment: But when I tried to update 3 fields then it shows error in syntax

Comment: I repeat: You should rather show the statement as produced by the Debug.Print !